# css shape-outside Как контролировать обтекание для изображения

Tags: css, css3, shape-outside

Пробую организовать обтекание изображения текстом как показано на рисунке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.best_girl {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  shape-outside: url("../images/box/girl-India.png");
  shape-image-threshold: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<img class="best_girl" src="images/box/girl-India.png" width="419" height="341" alt="Indian girl" loading="lazy">
```

Не могу понять почему область тени обтекания в инспектори отображаеться по правому нижнему краю, возможно ли как-то смещать эту область ? (Это не то что мне сейчас надо) * кроме `shape-margin:` свойства, это тут не подходит. Если нельзя, то может кто-то подсказать как быстро перегнать изображение в path для `shape-outside: polygon(...)`

Comment: Чтоб быстро полигон получить можете использовать [генератор](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) (укажите url своей картинки), выберете custom polygon и после окончания скопируйте координаты в процентах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаю как быстро перегнять изображение в path.

1. В любом редакторе заливаем нужное изображение черным. Вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Качаем и истанавливаем inkscape
3. Импортируем черное изображение в inkscape File > Import
4. Переводим изображение в вектор Path > Trace Bitmap. Откроется окно, в нем можно настроить сглаживание и точность
5. Смотрим полученный результат в xml редакторе Edit > XML Editor. Или сохраняем в svg
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо буду знать, а как из path перейти в polygon ? Там же вроде в процентных отношениях уже

Comment: Извините, не учел этого. Есть разные конвертеры, например https://betravis.github.io/shape-tools/path-to-polygon/

Comment: Или вручную :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679495/examples-of-polygons-drawn-by-path-vs-polygon-in-svg

Comment: и по вашим словам получается что инкскейп сам раставит слова по по области изображения ?